# Can I mock out an included module?

Tags: unit-testing, rspec, mocking

#### It's easy to mock out a module when it's included explicitly, like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    MyHelper.sometimes_true_sometimes_false
end
```

#### In the spec, you simply write:

```
MyHelper.should_receive(:sometimes_true_sometimes_false).and_return true
```

### In Context:

*module*

```
module MyHelper
    def sometimes_true_sometimes_false
        [true, false].sample
    end
end
```

*controller*

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    def myaction
        if MyHelper.sometimes_true_sometimes_false
            @message = "Congratualtions, it's true"
        else
            @message = "Sorry, it's false"
        end
    end
end
```

*spec*

```
describe 'GET #myaction'
    subject { get :myaction }
    context 'when it\'s true' do
        before do
             MyHelper.should_receive(:sometimes_true_sometimes_false).and_return true
        end
        specify { expect(assigns(:message)).to eq "Congratulations, it's true" }
    end
    context 'when it\'s false' do
        before do
             MyHelper.should_receive(:sometimes_true_sometimes_false).and_return false
        end
        specify { expect(assigns(:message)).to eq "Sorry, it's true" }
    end
end
```

## But how should I write the spec when the module is included into the controller, and the class method called natively, like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    include MyHelper

    sometimes_true_sometimes_false
end
```

### In Context:

*controller*

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    include MyHelper

    def myaction
        if sometimes_true_sometimes_false
            @message = "Congratualtions, it's true"
        else
            @message = "Sorry, it's false"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite easy actually, thought of the answer while I was creating my answer (and going mental with the title tags):

#### You simply write:

```
MyController.any_instance.should_receive(:sometimes_true_sometimes_false).and_return true
```

*spec*

```
describe 'GET #myaction'
    subject { get :myaction }
    context 'when it\'s true' do
        before do
             MyController.any_instance.should_receive(:sometimes_true_sometimes_false).and_return true
        end
        specify { expect(assigns(:message)).to eq "Congratulations, it's true" }
    end
    context 'when it\'s false' do
        before do
             MyController.any_instance.should_receive(:sometimes_true_sometimes_false).and_return false
        end
        specify { expect(assigns(:message)).to eq "Sorry, it's true" }
    end
end
```